# Issue with Qt slider signal/GUI

Tags: xcode, user-interface, qt, slider

When a user moves the slider it will trigger a signal and based on that I want to call a method `readData` from `dataClass`, to return me a string and then print it in `guiClass`. But it does not work. I get Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. I am using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). As soon as I move the slider the program crashes and highlights line 9.

```
 1  //---guiClass---
 2  guiClass::guiClass(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
 3  {
 4      connect(slider, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), this, SLOT(slider_Moved(int)));
 5  }
 6  void guiClass::slider_Moved(int val)
 7  {
 8      //Don't worry about val for now.
 9      cout << dataClassPtr->readData(val) << endl;
10  }

    //---dataClass---
    char* dataClass::readData(int lines) {
       char *str = "hello world";
       return str;
    }
```

Comment: i used the <pre><code> tags but i dont know why the code is not showing properly!!!

Comment: Indent the code with 4 spaces on each line, it will format it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pointer str in dataClass::readData is allocated on the stack. You can't use it once the function has returned.

Try something like:

```
QString* dataClass::readData(int lines) 
{
    return new QString("hello world"); 
}
```

Don't forget to delete the QString when you are finished with it

Comment: so if i allocate memory for str using calloc and then return a pointer to that? will that work?

Comment: That should do it.  
Or create a QString with new()

Comment: I tried the following:

char* dataClass::readData(int lines)

 char *memData = (char *)calloc(30, sizeof(char));

 char *data = "hello world";

 sprintf(memData, "%s", data);

 return memData;

}

but no luck!!! what am i doing wrong??

Comment: You don't need calloc for the string data, you need it for the pointer to the string.

Comment: char \*str = "hello world"; shouldn't even compile (or should give you a warning about being deprecated). "hello world" is const, so it should be char const\* str.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a debugger (if you don't know how, learn :-)
2. Verify that `dataClassPtr` points to a valid instance of `dataClass`
3. `char *str = "hello world"` is wrong (string literals are const; should be `const char* str`)
4. Why not have `readData` return a `QString` instead?